# Is it any way to connect ESP8266 to wifi faster?

Tags: esp8266, wifi, sketch

I'm uploading this sketch to try connecting ESP to internet. However, most of the times I've ran it it takes a very long time to connect, a lot of times I've had to break the process because it seems it goes to nowhere. Few times it has connected in less than a minute. Is it any alternative to boost the connection?

Also, when I reset the module, it writes to the terminal 3 strange characters, and freezes without even starting to execute its sketch. Do you mind me asking how to solve that?

Regards!

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char red[] = "CDT10";
const char pass[] = "G7ZSY74Cs";
unsigned long muestra = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(red,pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.print("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("Chip ID: "); Serial.println(ESP.getChipId());
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
  muestra = millis();
  Serial.println(muestra);
}
```

Comment: Which board are you using?

Comment: Right now, ESP-01.

Comment: is the bandwidth ok once it connects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also experienced the inability to connect sometimes. I wait a certain amount of time for it to connect then do a ESP.reset() if it fails.

As for the boot problem it sounds like you are keeping GPIO0 low so it goes back into programming mode. Hold it high and it will run your program instead.

Comment: It worked! I forgot to hold high the GPIO0. Now it is running right. Thanks!